# How do I vary amount of items in listView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

This is just a question I'm wondering about, not a problem I encountered.
For example if my app received multiple information from server, I want to display them all in listView, but how do I make the app have amount of items it received? Another way of saying it is make certain amount of item displayed based on item count received from the server? It should be like the app received 3 messages, display those 3 messages in a listView.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on listview height, and height of individual view in listview.

Listview will automatically accommodate as much as it can. This thing we wont need to worry about.

One thing we should consider, is about the number of messages in array/list which is being populated in Listview. 
If count is high then we should use RecyclerView.  This will eliminate case of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView offers you much more control over your lists.

You can set the size of the list in a callback:

```
// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

Try RecyclerView:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview